# ADFS and two Servers on two domains - iframe - prompted twice?

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, iframe, adfs2.0, office365

My employer has a local ADFS server. We are using o365/SharePoint Online with ADFS so when you attempt to access a SharePoint cloud site you are take to login page on our network.

I need to develop a simple ASP.NET C# website hosted locally on a server on a network.

1. At a high level what is entailed in using ADFS on asp.net/iis websites? And can it be set so that the same login page is used?
2. If I have a webpage on a local webserver authenticated by the same ADFS and Iframe that page inside a sharePoint web page authenticated by the same ADFS. Should the page with render without authenticating?

Answer (score 0):

1) I'd recommend checking into [Windows Identify Foundation (WIF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377151.aspx). Although your app will need to run under TLS/SSL, you probably will just need to run the FedUtil.exe application to generate your application's metadata for ADFS to consume when creating an RP.

2) In theory this might work, but the Iframe'd page will still redirect to ADFS momentarily to get an authentication token. It is just that the login page won't be displayed.